# available security roles in elasticsearch-jetty plugin

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch-jetty plugin and trying to use it for the authentication of elasticsearch access. 
I am wandering which security roles are available for users specified in realms.properties. I couldn't find definite list.
I saw in examples usage of: admin, readwrite and read-only. Are there any other and where can I specify new ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just found that roles are defined inside of jetty-restrict-*.xml files, depending on which is used. For default jetty-restrict-all.xml file, only "readwrite" role is defined, but for jetty-restrict-write.xml role "admin" is also used.

That is also the place where other roles can be defined.